# Get ID of Tooglebutton

Tags: wxpython

I am generating a couple of toggle buttons based on a database request and ids are assigned, using wx.ID_ANY.

I couldn't find a possibility to deal with these toggle buttons in a way as it is  possible with radio buttons (style=wx.RB_GROUP). Therefor, I was thinking to retrieve the id of the toggle button after creation, and store them in a list.
On click event from any of the buttons I can iterate over the list...

```
for proj in db_data:
        proj_btn = wx.ToggleButton(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        proj_btn_lst.append(proj_btn.GetID())
```

When running the code with the code piece from above I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'ToggleButton' object has no attribute 'GetID'`

Does any of you have a solution for the problem with the toggle buttons or the one on how to get the id?

Comment: Please either answer the question as an answer, or close the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the way on how to retrieve the id: `proj_btn_lst.append(proj_btn.GetId())`